Nginx not serving a NEXT JS 13 route
I have deployed my next js website on Aws ec2 and I am using Nginx to reverse proxy the request to port 3000. This setup works, But what i want is not to serve the home page but a particular page. Here is my Nginx conf which works:
server {
    server_name mydomainname;

    proxy_connect_timeout 5m;
    proxy_send_timeout 30m;
    proxy_read_timeout 30m;
    

    location / {
        proxy_pass_header Server;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";    }

}

But I want to serve another page eg: http://localhost:3000/myPage here is the conf for this:
server {
    server_name mydomainname;

    proxy_connect_timeout 5m;
    proxy_send_timeout 30m;
    proxy_read_timeout 30m;
    

    location / {
        proxy_pass_header Server;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/myPage;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";    }

}

This does not work it shows a white blank page and in the console there are some errors like this
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

I want to know can this work? and if it is not working then what is the reason? Also I do know that we can rewrite in next for this kind of work but I am just curious why is this happening???
